# SQL joining similar SELECTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

I have two similar SELECT statements trying to get an overlap where dataset for a specific user and another are the same. I have the following but keep getting the error:

> Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
>     The column 'PermissionId' was specified multiple times for 'T1'.
>
> Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 40
>     The column 'PermissionId' was specified multiple times for 'T2'.

```
SELECT TOP 100 T1.Name, T1.permissionId
FROM (SELECT top 100 n.Name, rp.permissionId, rp.*
FROM dbo.[User] AS u
    JOIN dbo.UserRole AS ur ON ur.UserId = u.UserId
    JOIN dbo.ClientRole as cr on cr.RoleId = ur.RoleId
    JOIN dbo.Name as n2 on cr.NameId = n2.NameId 
    JOIN dbo.RolePermissions AS rp on rp.RoleId = ur.RoleId
    JOIN dbo.SystemTaxonomy AS st on st.SystemTaxonomyId = rp.PermissionId
    JOIN dbo.Name AS n on st.NameId = n.NameId

WHERE u.LoginName IN ('user1')) AS T1
JOIN (SELECT top 100 n1.Name, rp1.permissionId, rp1.*
FROM dbo.[User] AS u1
    JOIN dbo.UserRole AS ur1 ON ur1.UserId = u1.UserId
    JOIN dbo.ClientRole as cr1 on cr1.RoleId = ur1.RoleId
    JOIN dbo.Name as n2 on cr1.NameId = n2.NameId 
    JOIN dbo.RolePermissions AS rp1 on rp1.RoleId = ur1.RoleId
    JOIN dbo.SystemTaxonomy AS st1 on st1.SystemTaxonomyId = rp1.PermissionId
    JOIN dbo.Name AS n1 on st1.NameId = n1.NameId
WHERE u1.LoginName IN ('user2')) AS T2
ON T1.rp.permissionId = T2.rp1.permissionId
```

Can someone please guide me as to what is wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at      rp.permissionId, rp.*      and try rp.permissionId AS Perm_ID, rp.* or remove rp.permissionId

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using derived tables, you must use unique column names.
You are selecting the `PermissionId` column twice from `rp` in the first derived table and from `rp1` in the second derievd table.
Remove the explicit `rp.permissionId,` and `rp1.permissionId,` from your derived table and you should not see these errors again:

```
SELECT TOP 100 T1.Name, T1.permissionId
FROM (SELECT top 100 n.Name, rp.*
FROM dbo.[User] AS u
    JOIN dbo.UserRole AS ur ON ur.UserId = u.UserId
    JOIN dbo.ClientRole as cr on cr.RoleId = ur.RoleId
    JOIN dbo.Name as n2 on cr.NameId = n2.NameId 
    JOIN dbo.RolePermissions AS rp on rp.RoleId = ur.RoleId
    JOIN dbo.SystemTaxonomy AS st on st.SystemTaxonomyId = rp.PermissionId
    JOIN dbo.Name AS n on st.NameId = n.NameId

WHERE u.LoginName IN ('user1')) AS T1
JOIN (SELECT top 100 n1.Name, rp1.*
FROM dbo.[User] AS u1
    JOIN dbo.UserRole AS ur1 ON ur1.UserId = u1.UserId
    JOIN dbo.ClientRole as cr1 on cr1.RoleId = ur1.RoleId
    JOIN dbo.Name as n2 on cr1.NameId = n2.NameId 
    JOIN dbo.RolePermissions AS rp1 on rp1.RoleId = ur1.RoleId
    JOIN dbo.SystemTaxonomy AS st1 on st1.SystemTaxonomyId = rp1.PermissionId
    JOIN dbo.Name AS n1 on st1.NameId = n1.NameId
WHERE u1.LoginName IN ('user2')) AS T2
ON T1.permissionId = T2.permissionId
```

However, I suspect this is an [XYProblem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps it would be better to describe your goal rather then your attempts to get there.

Comment: had to change the last line: ON T1.rp.permissionId = T2.rp1.permissionId

Answer (score 1):

The select statement cannot display multiple column with same name.Use alias for rp.permissionId in the select statement

```
SELECT top 100 n.Name, rp.permissionId As 'Permission_Id', rp.*
```

Also, please check if the last join condition

```
ON T1.rp.permissionId = T2.rp1.permissionId
```

is working fine. rp & rp1 are internal to T1 & T2 derived tables. They can't be recognized externally. 
You can replace with below instead

ON T1.permissionId = T2.permissionId

Comment: Was the second part useful?

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
SELECT TOP 100 T1.Name, T1.permissionId
FROM (SELECT top 100 n.Name, rp.*
FROM dbo.[User] AS u
    JOIN dbo.UserRole AS ur ON ur.UserId = u.UserId
    JOIN dbo.ClientRole as cr on cr.RoleId = ur.RoleId
    JOIN dbo.Name as n2 on cr.NameId = n2.NameId 
    JOIN dbo.RolePermissions AS rp on rp.RoleId = ur.RoleId
    JOIN dbo.SystemTaxonomy AS st on st.SystemTaxonomyId = rp.PermissionId
    JOIN dbo.Name AS n on st.NameId = n.NameId

WHERE u.LoginName IN ('user1')) AS T1
JOIN (SELECT top 100 n1.Name, rp1.*
FROM dbo.[User] AS u1
    JOIN dbo.UserRole AS ur1 ON ur1.UserId = u1.UserId
    JOIN dbo.ClientRole as cr1 on cr1.RoleId = ur1.RoleId
    JOIN dbo.Name as n2 on cr1.NameId = n2.NameId 
    JOIN dbo.RolePermissions AS rp1 on rp1.RoleId = ur1.RoleId
    JOIN dbo.SystemTaxonomy AS st1 on st1.SystemTaxonomyId = rp1.PermissionId
    JOIN dbo.Name AS n1 on st1.NameId = n1.NameId
WHERE u1.LoginName IN ('user2')) AS T2
ON T1.permissionId = T2.permissionId
```